# Fixing duplicate rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table like below

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE 
(
  id int, 

  value nvarchar(50)
)
```

which has following value

```
1, 'abc'
2, 'abc'
1, 'abc'
3, 'abc'
```

I want to update this table so that it has the following values

```
1, 'abc'
2, 'abc_1'
1, 'abc'
3, 'abc_2'
```

Could someone help me out with this

Comment: So it's okay if the rows are actually duplicates (there's two `1,abc` rows) but if the values are duplicates but the IDs are different, then you append `_` and the ID minus 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use a cursor to move over the table and try to insert every row in a second temporary table. If you get a collision (technically with a `select`), you can run a second query to get the maximum number (if any) that's appended to your item.

Once you know what maximum number is used (use `isnull` to cover the case of the first duplicate) just run an update over your original table and keep going with your scan.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to remove duplicates? or just change the values so they aren't duplicate?

to change the values use

update producttotals
set value = 'abc_1'
where id =2;

update producttotals
set value = 'abc_2'
where id =3;

to find duplicate rows do a 
select id, value 
from producttotals
group by id, value
having count() > 2;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or greater

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE 
(
  id int, 

  value nvarchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @ProductTotals
VALUES (1, 'abc'),
        (2, 'abc'),
        (1, 'abc'),
        (3, 'abc')


;WITH CTE as 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by value order by id) rn,
    id,
    value
FROM
    @ProductTotals),
new_values  as (
SELECT
    pt.id,
    pt.value,
    pt.value + '_' +  CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by pt.value order by pt.id) as varchar) new_value



FROM
    @ProductTotals pt
    INNER JOIN CTE
    ON pt.id = CTE.id
     and pt.value = CTE.value   
WHERE
    pt.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1)) --remove any with the lowest ID for the value

UPDATE
    @ProductTotals 
SET
    pt.value = nv.new_value
FROM 
@ProductTotals pt 
inner join new_values nv
ON pt.id = nv.id and pt.value = nv.value

SELECT * FROM @ProductTotals
```

Will produce the following

```
id          value
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           abc
2           abc_1
1           abc
3           abc_2
```

**Explanation of the SQL**

The first CTE creates a row number Value. So the numbering gets restarted whenever it sees a new value

```
rn                   id          value
-------------------- ----------- --------
1                    1           abc
2                    1           abc
3                    2           abc
4                    3           abc
```

The second CTE called new_values ignores any IDs that are assoicated with with a RN of 1. So rn 1 and rn 2 get removed because they share the same ID. It also uses ROW_NUMBER() again to determine the number for the new_value

```
id          value  new_value
----------- ------ -------------
2           abc    abc_1
3           abc    abc_2
```

The final statement just updates the Old value with the new value

Comment: But what if value abc_1 already exists in table. Could you make then make the changed value for id 2 to be abc_2